# How can I create an executable uber jar for spring boot with gradle?

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, uberjar

I'm aware that with the traditional "gradle build" command I can create what Spring boot calls an "executable jar".

This jar contains all the jar dependencies needed inside the jar's lib folder.

What I need is that, instead of copying the dependency jars inside the lib folder inside the executable jar, I want a full blown uber jar, that instead of having its dependencies as jars inside a lib folder, I need them extracted as packages/classes.

I already tried the shadow plugin to no avail, and I see nowhere how to create an uber jar, actually most Spring users and the documentation tend to mix in the uber jar term with the executable jar, so it's hard to get developers to understand that they are different packaging strategies even though the result tends to function the same way when running the java -jar command.

Comment: I am curious why you would want to do that?

Comment: There is some OSGi stuff I use with Spring, and as Spring deprecated OSGi support since DM was killed, the only way to use it is to explode the jars and limit its use to the declared bundle. Also, I know how to expand jars using Maven but I've never done this with Gradle, I can't get it to work, even if using the shadow plugin

Answer (score 1):

See the [shadow](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow) gradle plugin, it does what you want

Comment: Hi Lance, like I mentioned, I already tried to use the shadow plugin but doesn't work, maybe there's something special I need to add so it works correctly but I don't know what.
Currently the shadow plugin only expands the core spring boot jar, but leaves other jars in the lib folder and I don't know why.
Do you have any working example what could make it work?